# I accidentally deleted my partition using pvcreate(lvm)

Tags: partitioning, lvm

Good night folks

I accidentally deleted my data partition using something like:

```
 sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

I using Kubuntu 14.04. When i type

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I see:

```
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   204802047   102041600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       204802048  1699842047   747520000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1699844094  1953523711   126839809    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1699844096  1715466239     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6      1715468288  1953523711   119027712   83  Linux
```

But I can not access my data any more. Sorry my English... I hope someone can help(There something like 400gb data on sda3).
There a chance to recovery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) that can be used for recovery.

They both come in the same package, so all you have to install is `TestDisk`.  To install it, type in the following in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

---

**TestDisk** is used for Partition recovery, if the partition is still intact on the hard drive.  It can scan for them.  If it finds the old one, you have the option of writing out that partition back to the drive.

This application requires elevated permissions to run, so it would be launched as:

```
sudo testdisk
```

---

**PhotoRec** on the other hand is used for photo and data recovery.  It can scan through your entire drive recovering files of your choosing and saving them to a folder of your choice.

This application requires elevated permissions to run, so it would be launched as:

```
sudo photorec
```

---

The process of recovering your data can take a while to perform.  Here are the step-by-step processes for recovering data.

[TestDisk - Step-By-Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

[PhotoRec - Step-By-Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

**Note:** as with any data recovery process there is no 100% guaranteed fail proof way of recovery.  It is always recommended to back up your data before you start any partitioning of hard drives.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! I read the step by step from the testDisk and it works!

Comment: @LGM That is awesome!  Glad you got it fixed!!  =)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) helped me recover data from a formatted hard drive. But the output given by the software was immense. It recovered over a million images.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved:-

I use the testDisk and it work! I just use the deep search and recover all data I want. Thank you all for help!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: Ok! I'll try help others now!

Comment: Please accept the helpful answer by clicking the check sign at the left of it. It will give some rep points to the person who answered, and will show others that the solution works. @LGM