# My hard disk partition has disappeared.. pls help me

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery, disk

I tried to reinstall ubuntu, so I used booting usb disk.

Yeah. I know it is very simple task, but i think that i made mistake.

I checked icon which named "Linux LVM", and I wanted to check which partition is good to install. So I select "Something else".

However... Every partition was disappeared. I totally don't know what to do.

I had 5 partitions,
2 for Windows
1 for Windows system reserved
1 for Ubuntu
1 for Swap partition

and this is a situation now. I use my ubuntu usb disk, and

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2e1f958d

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1953523711 1952522242  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1953523711 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM
```

Sorry for my bad English. I try to google it, but i can't find answer

How can i recover my hard disk partition?
Is it right that delete LVM??

below screenshot is that i used testdisk

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND1TQ.png)
[What i want to recover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eblQM.png)

Comment: I wrote this answer a while ago.  http://askubuntu.com/a/690414/231142

Comment: i can't figure out what is logical partition, or primary partition. @Terrance

Comment: Usually the Primary is marked with a P at the beginning of the line.  That can always be fixed later.  The idea is to look for what Partitions you had before and recover them.