# Help - unfamiliar screen appears instead of GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

Instead of the purple GRUB screen, everything I see when I try to boot is this. How to fix this?

Edit: Yes, I have multiple partitions. I recently tried to expand the size of the partition in which Ubuntu is installed (using GParted), but I cancelled the operation in the middle of the process because it was taking too long. When I tried to log in again, a message of error appeared. I then searched the web for a solution and I found a couple of terminal commands to reinstall GRUB. The result was this same screen below.

[image]

Comment: Did you recently install an OS?  Do you have multiple hard drives in the computer where you might have Ubuntu installed on another drive?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024473/edit) your question and give us some more information about your computer.  If it doesn't say `grub rescue` that usually means that it is not seeing an installation of Ubuntu or a Linux on the system.

Comment: Sounds like your Ubuntu partition is messed up.  That can happen from cancelling or stopping a resize in the middle of it.  You can try booting from a LiveCD and then using TestDisk to get your partition back.   See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/690414/231142

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot Ubuntu after trying to mount partition in windows with ext2fat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145102/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-after-trying-to-mount-partition-in-windows-with-ext2fat)

Comment: "I recently tried to expand the size of the partition in which Ubuntu is installed (using GParted), but I cancelled the operation in the middle of the process because it was taking too long." this almost certainly wrecked your system - the process copies and moves information located on the partition you are modifying

Answer (score 0):

Try entering `insmod normal` and then type `normal` to see if the system can boot normally from here.