# Unable to boot Ubuntu after trying to mount partition in windows with ext2fat

Tags: grub2

I recently tried to access my Ubuntu partition from windows to access some files using ext2fat. Once I tried booting back into Ubuntu I get the grub error “Minimal BASH like line editing is supported...”. I’ve already tried boot-recovery with no success, reinstating Ubuntu is not an option as I need some of the data. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you are getting the black screen grub prompt?

Comment: Yeah it just says grub>

Comment: OK. You can boot fully into Ubuntu from there if that's what you still want to do. I've posted an answer to this some time ago which I'm trying to find. Meanwhile boot into Live Ubuntu, run command `sudo parted -l` and post output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **ext2fat** corrupts Ubuntu partitions, as do other Windows drivers that say they'll let you read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions. **Uninstall it asap**. Then do a file system check on Ubuntu, like so...

**For 17.10 or older...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**For 18.04 or newer...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Note**: if you wish to share files between Ubuntu and Windows, create a NTFS partition that both can read/write to.

Comment: when i run the command it gives this output:
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda4
Could this be a zero-length partition?

Comment: @CalebSordelet  Were you either in recovery mode, or booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? You can't run fsck on a mounted file system. If that's not the case, show me a screenshot of gparted... put it on imgur.com and give me the URL.

Comment: im in a live usb

Comment: @CalebSordelet Go ahead and get the gparted screenshot. Let me know when I can see it.

Comment: actually im using testdisk right now and im able to recover my data that i need, i will just reinstall ubuntu, thanks for your suggestions and time!

Comment: @CalebSordelet good enough. Remember to uninstall ext2fat asap.