# contents unknown in disks under gpt partition

Tags: gpt

I changed the partition type to gpt on top but after changing this the,disks are showing the hard drive partition as contents as known and file system as unallocated space.I can't see my files and data of the hard drive.Here is the screenshot ---
[disks].

PLease somebody help me.

Comment: Unless you have a good backup, changing the partitioning type from MBR to GPT wipes out your partitions.  You can try booting to Live CDs and installing and running testdisk to try to recover your software / partitions.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/690414/231142

Comment: Using Ubuntu? How did you "changed the partition type to `GPT`"? Why? The GPT/MBR each describe the DISK and where its partitions are. They are not compatible.